# Spring Clould Stream Resolving Input Channel dynamically based on Message

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I need a way of resolving an Inbound Channel dynamically based on the type of the Incoming Message. 
I am not looking for any header based solution which is already mentioned in this link
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.0.M1/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streamlistener_for_content_based_routing

The resolution has to happen based on the type of the message. If there is a custom binding that can be done at application startup to be able to do this, that should be ok; Please give me some samples on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such support in Spring Cloud Stream.

The underlying Spring for Apache Kafka project does have support for such scenarios.

[See `@KafkaListener` on a Class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#class-level-kafkalistener).

It requires the payload to have been deserialized by the Kafka deserializer; then the method called depends on the payload type.

It also supports a fallback "default" method.

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "multi", topics = "myTopic")
static class MultiListenerBean {

    @KafkaHandler
    public void listen(String foo) {
        ...
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    public void listen(Integer bar) {
        ...
    }

    @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
    public void listenDefault(Object object) {
        ...
    }

}
```